# .Net Core MongoDB Identity CurrentUser Null

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core, .net-5, asp.net-core-identity

I have been working on implementing .Net 5 Identity for MongoDB. When an user logins into the system, I can not catch the user from ***_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name***. Name is always null.

When I call this code _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name, it returns null.

Here is my Authentication implementations.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Adds authentication service
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="services">Collection of service descriptors</param>
    public static void AddSystemAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var appSettings = Singleton<AppConfig>.Instance;
        var mongoDbSettings = appSettings.MongoDbConfig;
        var jwtConfigs = appSettings.JwtConfig;

        services.AddIdentity<AppUser, AppRole>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
        })
        .AddMongoDbStores<AppUser, AppRole, string>
        (
            mongoDbSettings.ConnectionString, mongoDbSettings.Database
        )
        .AddUserManager<UserManager<AppUser>>()
            .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<AppRole>>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie();

        JwtTokenDefinitions.LoadFromConfiguration(jwtConfigs);
        services.ConfigureJwtAuthentication();
        services.ConfigureJwtAuthorization();
    }
```

Here is my launchSettings.json.

```
          {
          "iisSettings": {
            "windowsAuthentication": true,
            "anonymousAuthentication": false,
            "iisExpress": {
              "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:57064",
              "sslPort": 44393
            }
          },
          "profiles": {
            "IIS Express": {
              "commandName": "IISExpress",
              "launchBrowser": true,
              "launchUrl": "swagger",
              "environmentVariables": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
              }
            },
            "ChatCase.Api": {
              "commandName": "Project",
              "launchBrowser": true,
              "environmentVariables": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
              },
              "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
            }
          }
       }
```

Here is ConfigureJwtAuthentication.

```
public static void ConfigureJwtAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services)
                {
                    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                    {
                        options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    })
                        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                        {
                            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                            options.SaveToken = true;
                            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                            {
                                ValidateIssuer = true,
                                ValidateAudience = true,
                                RequireExpirationTime = true,
                                IssuerSigningKey = JwtTokenDefinitions.IssuerSigningKey,
                                ValidAudience = JwtTokenDefinitions.Audience,
                                ValidIssuer = JwtTokenDefinitions.Issuer,
                                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = JwtTokenDefinitions.ValidateIssuerSigningKey,
                                ValidateLifetime = JwtTokenDefinitions.ValidateLifetime,
                                ClockSkew = JwtTokenDefinitions.ClockSkew
                            };
                        });
                }
```

Here is ConfigureJwtAuthorization.

```
 public static void ConfigureJwtAuthorization(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthorizationCore(auth =>
        {
            services.AddAuthorizationCore(auth =>
            {
                auth.AddPolicy("BearerNegotiateNTLM ", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());
            });
        });
    }
```

Here is JwtTokenService.

```
/// <summary>
    /// Generates JWT token
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="appUserDto"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public TokenUserResponse GenerateToken(AppUserDto appUserDto)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, appUserDto.UserName),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, appUserDto.UserId.ToString()),
        };

        string accessToken = GenerateAccessToken(claims);
        string refreshToken = GenerateRefreshToken();
        var token = new TokenUserResponse
        {
            UserId = appUserDto.UserId,
            UserName = appUserDto.UserName,
            RegisteredDate = appUserDto.RegisteredDate,
            AccessToken = accessToken,
            RefreshToken = refreshToken,
            Expires = JwtTokenDefinitions.TokenExpirationTime.Ticks
        };

        return token;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Generates access token
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="claims"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string GenerateAccessToken(IEnumerable<Claim> claims)
    {
        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var securityTokenHanlder = handler.CreateToken(new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Issuer = JwtTokenDefinitions.Issuer,
            Audience = JwtTokenDefinitions.Audience,
            SigningCredentials = JwtTokenDefinitions.SigningCredentials,
            Subject = claimsIdentity,
            Expires = DateTime.Now.Add(JwtTokenDefinitions.TokenExpirationTime),
            NotBefore = DateTime.Now
        });
        string accessToken = handler.WriteToken(securityTokenHanlder);

        return accessToken;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Generates refresh token
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string GenerateRefreshToken()
    {
        var randomNumber = new byte[32];
        using (var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
        {
            rng.GetBytes(randomNumber);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(randomNumber);
        }
    }
```

Here is Login process.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// User login async
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="model"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpPost("login")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public virtual async Task<IActionResult> LoginAsync([FromBody] LoginRequest model)
    {
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, false);
 
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var appUser = await _userService.GetByUserNameAsync(model.UserName);

            var token = _tokenService.GenerateToken(new AppUserDto
            {
                UserId = appUser.Id,
                UserName = appUser.UserName,
                Email = appUser.Email
            });

            await _userActivityService.InsertAsync(nameof(AppUser), "UserLoggedIn");

            return OkResponse(token);
        }
        else
        {
            await _userActivityService.InsertAsync(nameof(AppUser), "UserLoginError");

            LoggerFactory.DatabaseLogManager().Error($"AccountController- LoginAsync error: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result)}");
            Result.Status = false;
            Result.Message = "Username or password are wrong !";
            return BadResponse(Result);
        }
    }
```

How can I handle it?

Comment: could you post your login process step and `ConfigureJwtAuthentication` custom implementation ? `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` value directly depend on how we login the user in and on the authentication step. And mongodb is an absolute innocent one.

P/s: I still doesn't get that which authentication mechanism you intend to use in this case, is that cookie or jwt ?

Comment: @GordonKhanhNg. I have just posted my login process and ConfigureJwtAuthentication custom implementation. I have also commented ConfigureJwtAuthorization. In addition, I am working on implement authentication mechanism.

Comment: hmm... Interesting... If our jwt token contain at least `"unique_name": "appUserDto.UserName goes here","nameid": "appUserDto.UserId goes here"`, then it should be good, otherwise... I would wait for some answer too